# Extracting date range from a messy table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have no clue how to do this. I want to extract rows with date ranges in logs table (ie 2021-12-11 - 2021-12-14), but the table row looks like this:

| l_logs |
| --- |
| l_ticket 12 null ae34a45fc-aafc-4dd2-e6f1-22c84csf51ee l_log_time 93 2021-12-11 18:36:00 2021-12-11 18:38:00 |

BETWEEN, ANY or LIKE won't do any good in this case. Maybe some kind of loop?

Comment: What are the names of the columns? What are they data types?

Comment: Are you showing several columns, or the content of one text column?

Comment: This is the output of just one row in one column. Everything is separated by a tab what you see here.

Comment: Tangential, but you should really invest time and effort into parsing and inserting this data in a more workable format upstream from your database. This is definitely possible to parse in SQL (on the back-end of whatever ETL is placing this data in the table in the first place) but it will lead to a lot less headaches in the future if you're able to properly parse the data upfront into a normalized table structure.

Comment: @esqew This is a database that I have no power to change. I can only select things from it. In this case I wanted to select range of dates from this mess.

Comment: Do all rows values have the same structure? i.e. same number of elements when treating a space as the delimiter?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately not. Some may have more or less elements, so that's not a constant.

Comment: So how can you identify where the timestamp is located?

Comment: Are the timestamps always the last 2 fields in the TSV (tab separated values)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The location doesn't matter, only if range of dates exists. I want to look for ex 12-05-2021 to 12-10-2021, but there's only one date/two dates per row so I don't know how to make a range because of the mess in that row.

Comment: If you don't know _where_ the dates are (or don't know a rule to find them), there you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

first part of query extract **full time** line using groups and then
simple **left** and **right** functions extract datetime part of string

```
select * from test_table;
                                                    l_logs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 l_ticket 12 null ae34a45fc-aafc-4dd2-e6f1-22c84csf51ee l_log_time 93 2021-12-11 18:36:00 2021-12-11 18:38:00
```

```
with s as (select 
          regexp_replace(l_logs,'.*l_log_time \d+ (\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*','\1') full_time
          from test_table) 
select left(full_time,19)::timestamp start_t ,right(full_time,19)::timestamp end_t from s;
```

results

```
       start_t       |        end_t
---------------------+---------------------
 2021-12-11 18:36:00 | 2021-12-11 18:38:00
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but the elements can be in different positions so it will not work unfortunately. Like log times in some rows can be in the middle, it varies....

Comment: i changed my query so that now it should find the right time